# Python interface to C++ COM dll

Tags: python, c++, com, ctypes

So I'm trying to interface with a COM object with Python and having some difficulty as I'm not much of a programmer. I've interface Python with c dlls before but not with COM dlls. But that may not necessarily be the source of the problem. Any help or suggestions would be very much appreciated.

I've been able to load the library with Python with:

```
CiGenUsb = pythoncom.MakeIID(CiGenUsb_string)
win32com.client.pythoncom.CoInitialize()
disp = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch(CiGenUsb)
```

I've been able to call some functions okay but not the following one. The function is defined in C++ as:

```
CIUsb_SendFrame([in] LONG nDevId, [in] BYTE* pFrameData, [in] LONG nSize, [out] LONG* pStatus);
```

The data I want to send with `CIUsb_SendFrame` -- the `pFrameData` array -- is first read in as an array of 160 integers with python. I then put that into a byte array (of 320 bytes):

```
frame_bytes_type = ctypes.c_ubyte * 320
frame_bytes = frame_bytes_type()
j=0
for i in range(0,320,2):
    frame_bytes[i] = intData[j]&0xff
    frame_bytes[i+1] = (intData[j]>>8)&0xff
    j=j+1
disp.CIUsb_SendFrame(0, ctypes.addressof(frame_bytes), ctypes.sizeof(frame_bytes),0)
```

The code runs but the frame that is output to the hardware which the code controls looks very wrong. And it seems to change run to run. So I assume the data being sent is not what's in `frame_bytes` but something random.

The COM library also has variant versions of all the functions for use in ActiveX Automation environments but I have even less of a clue on how to use that.

Thanks.

**Edit**: I have called `CoInitialize` which I've now included in the snippet above. `nDevId` set to 0 is correct. I'll try using something more correct for `*pStatus`. The hardware being controlled consists of 160 pixels which can each take a 2-byte value. But since the `CIUsb_SendFrame` function takes a `BYTE` array, I create the 320 element array and pass that.

Comment: Are you calling `CoInitialize` (or is it called by one of your imported modules)? Also is the `nDevID` 0 ok? You should also pass the last argument it might return useful info about the error. Are only the first 160 elements from `intData` array relevant here?

Comment: You don't have to edit your original post to reply to comments (although in this case it's ok, since you also modified the code snippet). Is this COM object defined in a custom dll? (i couldn't get `CIUsb_SendFrame` refs on the internet). If yes, does it work when called from elsewhere (C) ?

Comment: Yes, this is a custom dll written by the providers of the hardware. They provide sample code in C++ which works fine. In C++, the function is called as: 

`hr = pIHostDrv->CIUsb_SendFrame(lCurDev, (UCHAR *) sMapData, NUM_ACTUATORS*sizeof(short), &lStatus);`

The data is stored in the `sMapData` which was defined as:

`USHORT sMapData [160]  = {0x0000};`